# How to fill vector with values returned by a member function in C++03?

Tags: c++, boost, initialization, c++03

I would like to get the same behavior as this:

```
IdentifiersGenerator gen;
for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
  v.push_back(gen.getNextIdentifiers());
```

with syntax similar to:

```
IdentifiersGenerator gen;
std::vector<Identifiers> v(100);
std::generate(v.begin(), v.end(),
    std::bind1st(std::mem_fun(&IdentifiersGenerator::getNextIdentifiers), gen));
```

the above snippet gives the following error:

```
test/src/IdentifiersGeneratorTest.cpp:449:   instantiated from here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/backward/binders.h:100: error: no type named ‘second_argument_type’ in ‘class std::mem_fun_t<const Identifiers&, IdentifiersGenerator>’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/backward/binders.h:103: error: no type named ‘first_argument_type’ in ‘class std::mem_fun_t<const Identifiers&, IdentifiersGenerator>’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/backward/binders.h:106: error: no type named ‘first_argument_type’ in ‘class std::mem_fun_t<const Identifiers&, IdentifiersGenerator>’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/backward/binders.h:111: error: no type named ‘second_argument_type’ in ‘class std::mem_fun_t<const Identifiers&, IdentifiersGenerator>’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/backward/binders.h:117: error: no type named ‘second_argument_type’ in ‘class std::mem_fun_t<const Identifiers&, IdentifiersGenerator>’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/backward/binders.h: In function ‘std::binder1st<_Operation> std::bind1st(const _Operation&, const _Tp&) [with _Operation = std::mem_fun_t<const Identifiers&, IdentifiersGenerator>, _Tp = IdentifiersGenerator]’:
test/src/IdentifiersGeneratorTest.cpp:449:   instantiated from here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/backward/binders.h:126: error: no type named ‘first_argument_type’ in ‘class std::mem_fun_t<const Identifiers&, IdentifiersGenerator>’
```

Maybe this can be done even without `std::vector` default object initialization using e.g. `boost::make_function_input_iterator`.

**EDIT** OK, so I have realized that I can use `boost::bind` like so:

```
std::vector<AlarmIdentifiers> v(100);
std::generate(v.begin(), v.end(),
    boost::bind(&IdentifiersGenerator::getNextIdentifiers, &gen));
```

Anyone can share an approach to initialize the vector with pointer to member function instead of constructing and then generating inside it?

Comment: Is it okay to make a functor?

Comment: No, I need member function `IdentifiersGenerator::getNextIdentifiers`

Comment: You can get it using a functor.  I am asking if you are okay wrapping the call in a functor.

Comment: @DimChtz `std::bind` is C++11 and I have explicitly marked this question as C++03. I might use `boost::bind` though

Comment: posible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917168/functional-bind1st-and-mem-fun

Answer (score 1):

The reason this doesn't work:

```
std::bind1st(std::mem_fun(&IdentifiersGenerator::getNextIdentifiers), gen)
```

is that [`bind1st`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind12) requires a *binary* function whereas you are providing a *unary* one. There isn't a prepackaged C++03 solution to this, if `boost::bind` is an option I would just use that.

Otherwise, could write your own factory that takes a pointer to nullary member function and a pointer to the class and returns an object with `operator()` that invokes it.

Answer (score 0):

(posting here just for reference)

OK, so I have realized that I can use `boost::bind` like so:

```
std::vector<AlarmIdentifiers> v(100);
std::generate(v.begin(), v.end(),
    boost::bind(&IdentifiersGenerator::getNextIdentifiers, &gen));
```

Answer (score 0):

bind is really an 'old' and mostly obsolete way to achieve something similar to the much nicer lambda syntax.

```
IdentifiersGenerator gen;
std::vector<Identifiers> v(100);
std::generate(v.begin(), v.end(), [&](){ return gen.getNextIdentifiers(); });
```

you could also use generate_n

Comment: Again, lambdas are C++11 and I have explicitly marked this question as C++03